# Protractor - How to store the value of browser.executeScript in variable?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, testing, protractor

I am trying to store the value of browser.executeScript  inside a local variable in my it  block but I am not able to do so in all the cases it displays null.

I have tried  many ways so far

```
browser.executeScript('$("#txtName").css("border-left-color");').then(function (color) {
    console.log("This is color" + color);
});
```

Also this

```
function returnColor() {
    var a = browser.executeScript('$("#txtName").css("border-left-color");');
    return a;
}

function getColorCode() {
    var a = returnColor().then(function(list) {
        console.log("Output is ***************" + list);
        return list;
    });

    return a;
}
```

I am using this inside my spec as

```
   iit('', function() {        
    
             browser.executeScript('$("#txtName").css("border-left-color");').then(function (color) {
                console.log("This is color" + color);
            });
    
            returnColor();
    
    
        });
```

Will really appreaciate it someone can tell me how to do it properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have a `return` from the script:

```
function returnColor()
{
    return browser.executeScript('return $("#txtName").css("border-left-color");');
}
```

Note that you can also solve the same problem via [`getCssValue()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue):

```
var elm = element(by.id("txtName"));
elm.getCssValue("border-left-color").then(function (color) {
    console.log(color);
});
```