# Unable to get the text inside the monaco editor using protractor

Tags: protractor, monaco-editor

I am writing BDD tests for Monaco-editor using the protractor-cucumber framework. A while ago, I found about Monaco API's and how to set the value inside the editor programmatically. But this time,
I am unable to get the text inside monaco editor using protractor. Here's a sample of my code:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        let driver = browser.driver;
        // iframe ids

       let iframeID = 'editorFrame';

       let editorSpanXpath = '//div[@id="editorContainer"]//div[contains(@class, "monaco- editor")]//div[contains(@class, "editor-scrollable")]'
      // switching to the iFrame to perform tasks inside it
        browser.switchTo().frame(iframeID);

    // clicking on a div inside the editor to ascertain that
    // the browser knows where to  run the script

        driver.findElement(by.xpath(editorSpanXPath)).click();
         browser.executeScript('this.monaco.editor.getModels()[0].getValue()').then(function(editorText){
               let replaceString = 'abracadbra' + editorText
               browser.executeScript('this.monaco.editor.getModels()[0].setValue("' + replaceString + '")');
        }
        );
```

The problem here is that the value of 'editorText' keeps coming up null. On running my BDD tests, the value inside the editor is replaced by **'abracadabranull'**

The editor is initialized with some default text. And since the 'setValue' function is working, I figure that the browser driver has no trouble in getting the iFrame where the editor gets loaded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, it was a simple return statement that saved the day:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    let driver = browser.driver;
    // iframe ids

   let iframeID = 'editorFrame';

   let editorSpanXpath = '//div[@id="editorContainer"]//div[contains(@class, "monaco- editor")]//div[contains(@class, "editor-scrollable")]'
  // switching to the iFrame to perform tasks inside it
    browser.switchTo().frame(iframeID);

// clicking on a div inside the editor to ascertain that
// the browser knows where to  run the script

    driver.findElement(by.xpath(editorSpanXPath)).click();
     browser.executeScript('return this.monaco.editor.getModels()[0].getValue()').then(function(editorText){
           let replaceString = 'abracadbra' + editorText
           browser.executeScript(' return this.monaco.editor.getModels()[0].setValue("' + replaceString + '")');
    }
    );
```

Many thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100810/protractor-how-to-store-the-value-of-browser-execute-script-in-varriable) answer for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: `await driver.executeScript(' return this.monaco.editor.getModels()[0].setValue("' + text + '")');` worked for me!!