# Input values by pressing keys in selenium-webdriver javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, e2e-testing

When I want input values with selenium, I always used `sendKeys` with an `input` element. But now I'm dealing with a [Monaco Editor](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/) in web which doesn't have any `input` element inside. Plus, all the values are spread to many elements each line.

So I'm thinking to first click to focus on the editor, then input all values by simulating pressing the keyboard, like a real human user would do. But after googling for a while I'm still not sure how to do this.

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040985/unable-to-get-the-text-inside-the-monaco-editor-using-protractor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get the text inside the monaco editor using protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040985/unable-to-get-the-text-inside-the-monaco-editor-using-protractor)

Comment: @Infern0 Thanks for pointing out the programmatical approach! I'd prefer selenium simulating a real user who inputs via a keyboard though. The "select all and delete" thing works smoothly now when I use `Key.chord(Key.command, 'a')`.